# How can i loop through array and split values

Tags: javascript, arrays

List of options to i want to loop through

```
<select name="List" id="List">
    <option value="">-Select-</option>
    <option value="">id1@name1</option>
    <option value="">id2@name2</option>
    <option value="">id3@name3</option>
</select>
```

this is my approach but i am only able to get a signel index i want to split the values in this order A=id1 | B =name2

```
 var options = document.getElementById("List");
    options = options.split("@");
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        var option = options[i];
        var A = option[1];
        var B = option[0];
       alert(A+"|"+B);
    );
```

Comment: Your title doesn't state what your problem is. It's just a list of requirements. And your actual question content doesn't state a problem either, just what you want. What is the actual problem you are having? What ***specifically*** do you need help with, not what end result do you wish to achieve.

Comment: Also, please don't use quoting except when you're quoting something. You appear to be quoting yoruself. :-) And there's no [tag:sorting] here.

Comment: Your new title isn't better. State a question, not a requirement that you can't achieve.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thank you for you response, what i am trying to do is get values from a selector , loop through them and split them by "@", then after create an array were to pass them as key value, then print the new array as a list.

Comment: You also appear to be trying to use a `for` loop as the second argument to `new Array`. I suggest stepping back from your current task and working through a basic tutorial or book.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm trying to say is that in addition to telling us what you want to do, you need to tell us, **specifically**, what you are stuck on. For example, does your code produce any errors in the Console? If so, what is the error? What line is it on?

Comment: @ScottMarcus i have redefined my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var options = document.getElementById("List")
            /* As first options[0] value is -select- so i start loop fron index options[1] */ 
            for(var i =1; i <options.length; i++){
               /* You can't split options because it's a DOM object so you have to extract text inside option tag */
                var option=options[i].textContent.split('@');
                var A = option[0];
                var B = option[1];
            alert(A+"|"+B);
    
        }
```

```html
<select name="List" id="List">
        <option value="">-Select-</option>
        <option value="">id1@name1</option>
        <option value="">id2@name2</option>
        <option value="">id3@name3</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: its worked cheers